# Cannot connect to Sql Server in Amazon RDS with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-server-2008, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an application that has been developed with Codeigniter. It uses an SQL Server database, hosted in an Amazon RDS Instance. 
The application is using the mssql driver (I can't change it to sqlsrv, unfortunately).

The RDS instance is ok, I tried connecting to the database from an SQL Server client, and everything works perfect, but when I try to connect it in the CI application, I get the classic **"Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings."** error.

Is there a way to have a more descriptive error thrown by CI? I have lost a lot of time trying to solve this issue and I really don't know what else I should look.

> Notes:

- This was working fine some days ago. I had to make a copy of the CI app (which is hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance). I shared the AMI to a different AWS account, and created a new instance with it, but didn't change anything in the volume. Everything has been exactly copied from one place to the other.
- Php info tells me that the mssql driver is there and it is correct.
- The Security Groups in the RDS instance and the EC2 instance, are open to the world (I deleted all the restrictions in order to see if that was the problem)

I will really appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: I am assuming you have enabled the MSSQL extension by adding extension=php_mssql.dll to php.ini . If not can you enable it and try again.

Comment: Thanks Ali, yes the extension was installed. 
Fortunately, it is working now, and I just can't understand how. After 4 days of not being able to connect to the database, it suddenly started working without making any updates in the server configuration. :S